# Adding same values to other rows with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to pandas and did my first script to combine two worksheets into one. I have a lot of duplicate data across multiple rows and would like to add the same values from a column to the other duplicate rows if that makes sense. For example

Sheet 1.

```
 Name PhoneNumber ItemOrdered

Jack 123-423-1423    Pizza

Sam 345-234-2336     Pie
```

Sheet 2.

```
Name PhoneNumber Item Ordered

Jack     NA           Pie

Sam     345-234-2336     Pizza
```

When I joined the two sheets I get

```
 Name PhoneNumber ItemOrdered

Jack   123-423-1423    Pizza

Sam   345-234-2336      Pie

Jack      NA           Pie


Sam  345-234-2336     Pizza
```

How would I go about adding the phone number value for example to the second entry of jack?

Answer (score 0):

adding Jack's phone number to the entry might not be the most correct thing to do.

```
import numpy as np
df.loc[df['Name']=='Jack',:] == '123-423-1423'
```

What you should do:

```
df_name_phonenumber = df[['Name','PhoneNumber']].copy().drop_duplicates()
del df['PhoneNumber']
df = pd.merge(df, df_name_phonenumber, on='Name', how='left') # Assuming no repeated names
```

Comment: Gave that a try and the script runs without any errors but the output is still the same. Should i be running that when I first join the two excell files or after they have been concatenated.

Comment: you should do that after they have been concatenated.

Comment: I tried and it didnt work. I did find another solution tho.